# How to extract two fields using regex from asingle response having same two field several times

Tags: jmeter

I need to extract all 'guid' and 'type' field from the following string

`"data":[{"guid":"b1527e5d-4ca6-4ad1-b8e4-a931f7ea039d","name":"ABCD Notebook","type":"personal_owned","noteCount":4,"usn":0,"createdDateTime":1497499740000,"lastUpdatedDateTime":1506534933000,"sharedNoteBookAccountUpdateCount":0},{"guid":"d83c5719-0f21-470f-844d-9de8f80a1917","name":"First Notebook","type":"personal_linked","noteCount":5,"usn":66,"createdDateTime":1499680291000,"lastUpdatedDateTime":1499778620000,"sharedNoteBookAccountUpdateCount":133,"sharedNoteBookGuid":"9a923f08-79bf-48dc-88fa-101fbd40c7e3"},{"guid":"7980400b-95e9-4b70-998d-a34dffa26a73","name":"First Notebook","type":"personal_linked","noteCount":5,"usn":3642,"createdDateTime":1504003170000,"lastUpdatedDateTime":1504003186000,"sharedNoteBookAccountUpdateCount":41,"sharedNoteBookGuid":"a5a238ac-2264-414b-8fe7-fefc606e5356"},{"guid":"74daadb0-abe5-48ce-b323-c78921154b66","name":"OwnedByPranay, SharedToSuniyal","type":"personal_linked","noteCount":5,"usn":3643,"createdDateTime":1504004040000,"lastUpdatedDateTime":1504004058000,"sharedNoteBookAccountUpdateCount":16530,"sharedNoteBookGuid":"694b0cc9-4618-44eb-9209-899861ffdc0c"},{"guid":"e68fdf03-045b-4176-acf8-651448b5a6a8","name":"Read Later","type":"personal_linked","noteCount":0,"usn":3681,"createdDateTime":1505736381000,"lastUpdatedDateTime":1505736454000,"sharedNoteBookAccountUpdateCount":2468,"sharedNoteBookGuid":"aee52828-b191-48ab-872a-d447ec2b8ca0"}],"success":true}`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing it in 2 steps:

1. Extract "data" bit using [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor), the relevant configuration would be:

   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `data`
   - Regular Expression: `"data":(\[.*?\])`
   - Template: `$1$`
2. Extract "guid" and "type" from resulting JSON object using [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor) using the following configuration:

   - Apply to -> JMeter Variable -> `data` (or whatever reference name you used in the Regular Expression Extractor)
   - Variable Names: `guid;type`
   - JSON Path Expressions: `$..guid;$..type`
   - Match No: `-1`
   - Default Values: `NA;NA`